# Could not locate Performance Counter with specified category name 'Network Interface',

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to loop through all the performance counters in C# in "Network Category"/""Bytes Total/sec" and then get the NextValue on each once of the instance names but I am getting the error that that the Instance Name is not found. What I am doing is the following: First I use the following code to create all the performance counts on the specific category, and for each instance name I create a different performance counter:

```
NetworkPerformanceCounterArray = new PerformanceCounter[NetowrkInstanceNames.Length];
foreach (var instance in NetowrkInstanceNames)
{
   Console.WriteLine(instance);
   NetworkPerformanceCounterArray[tmpind] = new PerformanceCounter();
   NetworkPerformanceCounterArray[tmpind].CategoryName = "Network Interface";
   NetworkPerformanceCounterArray[tmpind].CounterName = "Bytes Total/sec";
   NetworkPerformanceCounterArray[tmpind].CounterName = instance;
   tmpind++;
}
```

But when I use the line NetworkPerformanceCounterArray[i].NextValue() to get the next value (for any of the instances) I get an exception (e.x. Could not locate Performance Counter with specified category name 'Network Interface', counter name 'Atheros AR8121_AR8113_AR8114 PCI-E Ethernet Controller').

The strange think is that the instance names are correct. For example if I create just one performance counter for 'Atheros AR8121_AR8113_AR8114 PCI-E Ethernet Controller' by hardcoding the name it works just fine. The strange thing is that the instance name 'Atheros AR8121_AR8113_AR8114 PCI-E Ethernet Controller' is exactly the same in both cases, I have used copy paste and double check every time.

Can someone please clarify things?

Comment: Is `NetowrkInstanceNames` a copy/paste error to stackoverflow or have you flipped the o and w in your code as well? Do you initialize tmpind?

Comment: Hi here is NetowrkInstanceNames "string[] NetowrkInstanceNames = category.GetInstanceNames();" Yes I have initialize tmpind. What do you mean "have you flipped the o and w"?

Comment: Net*wo*rkInstanceNames <-> Net*ow*rkInstanceNames. Just to make sure it's no stupid mistake using 2 different variables.

Comment: .CounterName = instance????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch. Just noticed

```
NetworkPerformanceCounterArray[tmpind].CounterName = "Bytes Total/sec";
NetworkPerformanceCounterArray[tmpind].CounterName = instance;
```

you're using the same element (`CounterName`) twice. I guess the 2nd line should use `InstanceName` instead.

Comment: Yes you are right. After changing the .CounterName to .InstanceName it works. After coding for more than 12 hours I guess I need some rest :). Thanks for all the responses.